# meteor: Bootstrap navigation not aligned properly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, nav

I'm trying to add a bootstrap navbar following this guide: http://robertdickert.com/blog/2014/05/09/set-up-navigation-with-iron-router-and-bootstrap/.  However the brand keeps appearing on a separate line from the list of links. ie (underscore is just to show the indent):

**Brand**
__Link1 Link2 Link3

This is the output from meteor list:

```
accounts-password  1.1.0* Password support for accounts
accounts-ui        1.1.5  Simple templates to add login widgets to an app
autopublish        1.0.3  Publish the entire database to all clients
bootstrap          1.0.1  Front-end framework from Twitter
iron:router        1.0.7  Routing specifically designed for Meteor
meteor-platform    1.2.2  Include a standard set of Meteor packages in your app
```

Here is the related html.  I didn't add any css code, only installed bootstrap via meteor add.

```
<template name="layout">
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      {{> nav}}
    </header>
      <body>{{> yield}}</body>
  </div>
</template>

<template name='nav'>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        {{> navBrand}}
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          {{> navItems}}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</template>

<template name="navBrand">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ pathFor 'home' }}">MyApp</a>
</template>

<template name='navItems'>
  <li class="{{ activeIfTemplateIs 'link1' }}">
    <a href="{{ pathFor 'link1'}}">Link1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="{{ activeIfTemplateIs 'link2' }}">
    <a href="{{ pathFor 'link2'}}">Link2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="{{ activeIfTemplateIs 'link3' }}">
    <a href="{{pathFor 'link3'}}">Link3</a>
  </li>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I didn't have bootstrap 3 installed.  Fixed it with:

```
meteor remove bootstrap
meteor add mizzao:bootstrap-3
```

Comment: Why don't you use the official package meteor add twbs:bootstrap https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap

Comment: cause i didn't know about it :)